# How can I create a sha256 fingerprint in openssl

Tags: openssl, sha256

I want to sha256 the fingerprint Use the openssl. 
I tried, but you have to sha1. What will i do?

I'm using OpenSSL 1.0.1f.

commands

```
openssl md5 * >rand.dat

openssl genrsa -rand rand.dat -aes256 2048 > server.key

openssl req -new -key server.key -sha256 -config openssl.cfg > server.csr

openssl x509 -fingerprint -sha256 -in server.csr -req -signkey server.key -extensions v3_req -extfile openssl.cfg -out server.cer
```

Changed from The default is the following:

```
[ CA_default ]
default_md  = sha256    # Change

[ req ]
req_extensions = v3_req     # Uncomment
```

Comment: [link]https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509.html#
-md2|-md5|-sha1|-mdc2
the digest to use. This affects any signing or display option that
uses a message digest, such as the -fingerprint, -signkey and -CA options.
If not specified then SHA1 is used. If the key being used to sign with is
a DSA key then this option has no effect: SHA1 is always used with DSA keys.

However, it does not seem to affect the fingerprint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I create a sha256 fingerprint in openssl

`-sha256` is correct.

---

There's an example of signing a server's CSR with your own CA using OpenSSL at [How do you sign OpenSSL Certificate Signing Requests with your Certification Authority?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297139/how-do-you-sign-openssl-certificate-signing-requests-with-your-certification-aut).

---

Based on the feedback, it appears SHA1 is hard coded when using `-fingerprint`. Below is from `<openssl dir>/apps/x509.c` (all OpenSSL apps, like `ca`, `x509`, `encrypt`, `decrypt`, etc are located in `apps/`). From around line 935 of `x509.c`:

```
else if (fingerprint == i)
    {
    int j;
    unsigned int n;
    unsigned char md[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    const EVP_MD *fdig = digest;

    if (!fdig)
        fdig = EVP_sha1();

    if (!X509_digest(x,fdig,md,&n))
        {
        BIO_printf(bio_err,"out of memory\n");
        goto end;
        }
    BIO_printf(STDout,"%s Fingerprint=", OBJ_nid2sn(EVP_MD_type(fdig)));
    ....
```

As far as `const EVP_MD *fdig = digest`, `digest` can be set. But I can't tell what switch is supposed to be used. From around line 475:

```
else if ((md_alg=EVP_get_digestbyname(*argv + 1)))
    {
    /* ok */
    digest=md_alg;
    }
```

That looks broke to me.

Comment: -fingerprint I tried to remove the but is unchanged.

Comment: Create a CA-signed certificate with reference to the link,but thumbprint and you will have SHA1.

Comment: It looks like a bug to me (see the additional information).

Comment: @user3353855 - I was thinking.... try placing the `-sha256` as the *last* option, too. If its the last option, `EVP_get_digestbyname` will return a good `EVP_MD` object that does not get over-written later with a bogus name (a bogus name returns `NULL`).